# Tracing Segmentation Fault in Qt

Tags: qt, debugging, segmentation-fault

I'm working on an embedded Linux application in Qt and am running into SIGSEGV problems that I'm unable to trace. I'd love to be able to post code but Qt Creator only shows me some assembly code and doesn't provide much of a stack to trace back through.

I can see that the crash happens in `QApplicationPrivate::notify_helper(QObject*, QEvent*)` after an attempt to branch to an invalid address. I can see that this was called by `QApplication::notify()` but that's all the stack information Qt Creator gives me. The only thing I can think of at this point is that previous segmentation faults looked like they had something to do with killing a QTimer (many of the timers I'm using are single shot) but I was dumped into the disassembly and could never determine which QTimer was causing the issue. That crash was sporadic while this one seems to be pretty consistent.

Can anyone suggest what I might be able to do to get some more information to allow me to track down the source of this fault? I can provide additional details as needed, though I might need to know where I should even be looking.

EDIT:
It turns out the cause of the previous error was an array index that wasn't properly bounds checked. I still occasionally see a crash that appears to be related to a QTimer as the disassembly points to `QObject::startTimer(int)` but I can't see any obvious cause in this case. Again, the stack provides no insight into which timer may be causing the problem; I can only see a call to `QTimer::start()` followed by `QObject:startTimer(int)`.

Comment: You need to build Qt from source in the debug mode, so that the debugger can trace into Qt's source. A segfault in `startTimer` usually means that you're using a dangling pointer to QObject, or have corrupted the object instance.

Comment: Yep you need debug symbols. You can also set object names to all your timers